# How to implement Underlay Following Sections in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying implement underlay following sections in SSRS. Is there any way to achieve this?

In crystal reports there is underlay following section check box through which we can achieve this. I want to use this feature because in my details section there is one column (unit area) which repeats its data in each row due to which the totals at group footer comes wrong (due to duplicate unit area)
Workaround to get correct totals will also work for me if underlay is not possible. I googled for underlay feature and the only solution I could find was of using Matrix as per below msdn post. Let me know if there are any other possible workarounds or solutions.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1284e27c-de34-4670-a214-67fbe18470b3/underlay-following-section-like-crystal-reports?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I had to read that thread to begin to understand what "Underlay" means in Crystal. Can you give us an example of what you are trying to achieve? Sounds like this will be easy using the Matrix and multiple groups.

Comment: I suggest totaling in SQL. If you provide a data example, I can show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been very frustrating to figure out, but I finally figured out how to mimic Crystal's *Underlay Following Sections* behavior in SSRS!!!  I stumbled across the solution and after finding it I have searched on the method I used and found many articles referencing it, but never equating it to the solution for mimicking Crystal's Underlay property.  Here's how I did it.

I had three groups - call them Company, Business, Employee - and details.  Traditionally, these groups would be laid out on separate rows like this:

Company

...............Business

..............................Employee

...............................................Details

Using a table, I put the columns all on the same row - the details row - instead of multiple rows.

Company...Business...Employee...Details

Now, this should result in duplicate values for each of the groups for every detail set in my dataset.  And if you have this set up and run it, you will see that's exactly what you get.  Let's fix it.

1. Click anywhere on the table to bring up the tablix control region.
2. Click on the control for the details row; this should highlight the row.
3. Open up Properties and scroll down to the section called *Other* and look for a property called ***HideDuplicates***.  There should be a drop down list with all your groups.
4. Select the group that represents the parent group, in my case it was Company.

This property basically hides all of the group duplicates providing you with the Underlay look you are looking for.  All you have to do is save and preview!

I used this method on other reports that I wanted one of the groups, say the Company group, to be on a line all by itself.  No problem, just remember that as far as the details row is concerned, the Business group is now the parent.

Hope this helps

Comment: I will try this out but it looks like this solution will work.